# LaTeX: space after every letter

Tags: latex

I want to define a LaTeX command that inserts a space after every letter.

So, If I add

```
\addSpaces{someText}
```

the result should be

```
s o m e T e x t
```

How could I achieve this?

Background: I want each letter to be underlined, but the line should be separated between the letters:

```
s o m e T e x t 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

NOT:
s o m e T e x t
_______________
```

Comment: So... did one of these work out for you? Still having trouble?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [soul package](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) for underlining.  For single words, you can use the `\addspaces` macro I wrote below.  (The macro will swallow the space between words. A simple workaround is to use \quad to increase the space between the words.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}% provides underlining

\makeatletter% since we're using a macro containing @
\newcommand{\addspaces}[1]{%
  \@tfor\letter:=#1\do{%
    \ul{\letter}\space
  }%
}
\makeatother% resets @ to its original meaning

\begin{document}

% Works fine for single words
\addspaces{Spaces}

% Note that spaces in between words aren't preserved -- use \quad to add extra space.
\addspaces{Spaced\quad and\quad underlined.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For programmatic manipulation of text I find it much easier to use perltex to define a perl function to do the code and then compile the document. See [CTAN](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/perltex/) here.

Here is a quick and dirty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{perltex}

\perlnewcommand{\ulspace}[1]{
$input = shift;
$input =~ s/(\w)/\\underline\{\1\} /g;
return $input;
}

\begin{document}

\ulspace{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

Compile with:

```
perltex --latex=pdflatex myfile.tex
```

Comment: This answer encouraged me to find the python version of perltex ;)